# Como plotar os fatores (spp) do resultado do metaMDS usando ggplot2, relacionados aos sitios de coleta no data frame original?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Dado o seguinte data frame:

```
dat<-data.frame(
  "sitio" = c("a", "a", "a",'a', "b", "b", "b", 'b', "c", "c", "c",'c'),
  "amostra"=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),
  "sp1"=c(1,3,3,2,4,2,1,5,3,6,1,5),
  "sp2"=c(1,3,3,2,4,2,1,5,3,6,1,5),
  "sp3"=c(1,3,3,2,4,2,1,5,3,6,1,5),
  "sp4"=c(2,3,4,1,5,3,1,5,5,8,9,1),
  "sp5"=c(3,4,3,1,6,7,5,8,3,1,3,2)
)
```

Quero ver o agrupamento das espécies de acordo ao sitio de coleta, plotando o resultado do `metaMDS`, usando ggplot2.

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
dmds<-metaMDS(dat[,3:7], distance = "bray", autotransform = FALSE)
mds1 <- dmds$points[,1]
mds2 <- dmds$points[,2]
plt<-cbind(dat,mds1,mds2)
spp<-dmds$species
ggplot(plt,aes(mds1,mds2, shape=sitio,color=sitio))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label=spp))
```

Tentei usar geom_text, etiquetando as espécies do MDS, mas como tem um número diferente de linhas, dá o seguinte erro.

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): label

Como poderia juntar o resultado do MDS com o data frame original para ter acesso as espécies e aos sitios, conseguindo visualizar tudo em um gráfico?

[[image: Seria algo assim, mas com os nomes das espécies]]

Seguindo o exemplo dado pelo @Imonferrari, o gráfico fica assim.

[image: Gráfico final seguindo o exemplo de Imonferrari]

Comment: Como seria seu gráfico final? Você quer postar sp1/sp2... nas cordenadas de mds1 e mds2 em spp?

Comment: Quero que os nomes das espécies apareçam nos mesmos pontos dos 'sitios' 'a', 'b' e 'c'.

Comment: esse ultimo plot é o resultado que você espera ou o resultado que você está gerando?

Comment: É o que espero, é só um exemplo, esse fiz usando geom_text(aes(label="spp")).

Comment: Certo, mas olha as espécies seriam as sp1, sp2 né? É que posso te ajudar com o ggplot mas não conheço o tipo de dado, aí gostaria de entender mais de como você quer o gráfico final

Comment: No caso você quer plotar os pontos de dmds$species? `ggplot(data=plt, aes(mds1, mds2)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = sitio, color = sitio)) +
  geom_text(data = spp, aes(MDS1, MDS2, label = especies))` Tipo isso?

Comment: Isso plotar as spp relacionadas a cada 'sitio'. Rodei seu exemplo, mas dá o mesmo erro.Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): x and y

Comment: opa, antes de fazer o gráfico rode `spp['especies'] <- rownames(spp)`, q cria uma coluna com o nome das espécies. Tinha faltado essa parte

Comment: @JorgeMendes dá erro também, porque do MDS1 e MDS2 são 5 linhas cada e o total do df são 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pivotar:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

teste <- plt %>% pivot_longer(
  cols = starts_with('sp'),
  names_to = 'species',
  values_to = 'values'
)
```

E depois plotar:

```
ggplot(teste, aes(mds1, mds2, shape = sitio, color = sitio))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(label = teste$species)
```

Comment: Isso, pensei em algo assim, colocar todas as spp numa coluna, mas não achei o jeito. Agora, que faço porque no meu data frame todas as espécies começam com letras diferentes e tenho 55.

Comment: As colunas seguem uma ordem? Caso elas sigam você pode fazer um slicing, onde está `cols`dentro do `pivot_longer` você colocaria algo: `cols = colnames(plt)[3:7]` nesse nosso data.frame de exemplo retornará : '"sp1" "sp2" "sp3" "sp4" "sp5"'.

Comment: Esse exemplo responde a sua dúvida?

Comment: Responde sim, obrigado. Rodei com seu exemplo no o df original, mas o gráfico não fica bom. Vou coloca-lo para que você o veja.

Comment: Tem como disponibilizar o dataset que você está usando completo? O que você quer que melhore no gráfico?

Comment: Não posso. Marquei a sua resposta como a melhor solução, realmente ajudou. Acontece que quando se põem todas as spp numa coluna só, ficam todas as etiquetas das spp uma em cima da outra.